# Duplicated prompt in Java console

Tags: java, console, prompt

I have the following codes, however it is always showing a duplicated prompt after the first round of looping. How can I prevent the prompt from showing twice?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;
    String choice = "";

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Continue / Exit: ");
        choice = scn.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        if (choice.equals("continue"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            number = scn.nextInt();
        }   
    }while(!choice.equals("exit")); 

}
```

**Program Output:**

```
Continue / Exit: continue
Enter a number: 3
Continue / Exit: Continue / Exit: exit    <--- Duplicated prompt here (how to remove the duplicate?)
```

I am suspecting it has something to do with the usage of scanner object for `string` and `int`.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and it will become clear.

Comment: @MattBall I already did, but debugger are only able to display the values of the variables but not stuff stored inside the string buffer. (correct me if I am wrong). It seems that the buffer is not flushed out causing duplicates.

Comment: **never ever check `boolean` values in conditions explicitly**. This is error prone and ugly. `if(x = true)` is **always** `true`. Whilst you are correctly using the comparison operator you _should_ be writing `while(!choice.equals("exit"))`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have edited the codes, can you lift off the -1 ?

Comment: Why would I downvote you for writing bad code? That's not what downvotes are for. I did not downvote, but I would suspect that a couple of people thought that your question lacks research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextInt()` doesn't read newlines, so you wind up with an empty line (just the linebreak after the int) in the `Scanner` buffer. This gets read when you next use `nextLine`, resulting in the program not waiting for user input. You need to do either this:

```
number = scn.nextInt();
scn.nextLine(); //advance past newline
```

or this:

```
number = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine()); //read whole line and parse as int
```

Read about `nextInt` and `nextLine` in [the Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:-

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
 int number = 0;
 String choice = "";
 do
  {
    System.out.print("Continue / Exit: ");
    choice = scn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    if (choice.equals("continue"))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
         number = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine()); 
    }
  }while(!choice.equals("exit"));

  }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged because they are _unhelpful_. What was the issue the OP was having? How can it be fixed? These questions are only answered by a line-by-line comparison. As such I do not deem this answer to he helpful.

Answer (score -2):

The buffer has a newline, you need to flush the buffer. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number = 0;
    String choice;

    do
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Continue / Exit: ");
        choice = scn.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        if (choice.equals("continue"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            number = scn.nextInt();
        }   
    }while(choice.equals("exit") == false); 

}
```

output is:

```
Continue / Exit: continue
Enter a number: 2
Continue / Exit: continue
Enter a number: 4
Continue / Exit: exit
```

Comment: -1 because creating a new Scanner for every iteration is bad practice, and there are cleaner ways to solve this problem. Also doesn't explain *why* this occurs.

Comment: @kviiri `nextLine()` to read int is not mutch better. Why is it bad practice?

Comment: @PeterRader, unnecessary garbage for one. Also, reading the line is *much* better since that's what the user wants to do here - read a line and treat it as an int.

Comment: @kviiri Scanner is unnecessary? This answer do not trust the input-values.

Comment: @PeterRader, yes, a Scanner for EACH iteration is unnecessary. You need exactly one Scanner object, there should be no need to create a new one for each iteration.

Comment: In every itteration you need the scanner. You mean `a new Scanner`?! Why? Speed? Memory? Do you think a `OutOfMemoryError` will be throws and not a `NumberFormatException`? Or do you think the user is pissed by wait for `Scanner` to be constructed?

Comment: @PeterRader, yes, I mean the fact that you *unnecessarily* create a new Scanner every iteration for absolutely no reason. Unnecessary objects mean unnecessary garbage. That's also error prone because you can waste data you didn't want to lose.

Comment: @kviiri My answer handle `123 abc` better than your answer did, you throw a `NumberFormatException` and i only take 123 and continue. So your code is more error-prone than mine. Your code misuse `nextString()` twice, first for read a int, second for read unneccessary buffer. My code release the Scanner early, your code do that late. Did you ever compare the two speeds? Mine is faster! At less over-time-memory-usage.

Comment: @PeterRader, the user's not inputting `123abc`. They clearly want a line delimited input (see their own example). Your code fails if the input is read from a file instead of keyboard input. Also, it's `nextLine()`, and I'm NOT misusing it. Overall, you should stop whining because you got downvoted - your answer is still bad and you shouldn't blame me for it.

Comment: @kviiri hey i upvoted your answer, why should i do this if i dislike your answer's upvote? You have no arguments and hide the answer's blame behind the voting and behind the fact that its a person, not a file. This is a pure technical discussion, please dont throw mud on it.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi What is your output?

Comment: @PeterRader, no arguments? Check the first comment again. Creating new Objects unnecessarily is bad practice, check. Cleaner ways to solve this, check. No explanation to WHY this occurs, probably the biggest check there is. I've wasted enough time with this already...

Comment: @kviiri The new Scanner is not unneccessarily, its because of save time and memory, check. Your way, not Cleaner way. That the buffer has a newline + javadoc explain it enougth. Hey you wasted my time too.